# Python embedded in bash not working

Tags: bash, python, sockets

I want to embed a small python script inside a bash script so that I can send a json object to a socket.
I have tried the following code:

```
python -c "$(cat << 'EOF'
import socket
import json

data = {'ip':192.168.1.150', 'status':'up'}

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 13373))
s.send(json.dumps(data))
result = json.loads(s.recv(1024))
print result
s.close()
EOF
)"
```

and this:
    python -c "
    import socket
    import json

```
data = {'ip':192.168.1.150', 'status':'up'}

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 13373))
s.send(json.dumps(data))
result = json.loads(s.recv(1024))
print result
s.close()
"
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
data = {'ip':192.168.1.150', 'status':'up'}
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm assuming this is because bash is interpreting this, not python. I've tested the code in a python script, and it works.
Also, do I need the -c option?

Apologies, I'm completely inexperienced in python, I've written some quite extensive bash scripting for the project I'm working on and need to send the output of these to sockets as json objects. Such a small snipped of embedded Python code seems by far the simplest answer, unless anyone has other suggestions.

Python version installed on CentOS Python 2.6.6

Answer (score 4):

The problem that you're having that results in the `SyntaxError` is that you don't have an opening single quote on the IP value in the `data` dict. You have:

```
data = {'ip':192.168.1.150', 'status':'up'}
```

You need:

```
data = {'ip':'192.168.1.150', 'status':'up'}
```

Comment: thanks @John. Coding at 3am and panicking my solution wasn't going to work. Appreciate your time and I should have noticed that.